# How to call a function in one React component by button click in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am making a pos system and I am trying to make the items appear on the list section when I click on each of them. My problem is that the Items section and the List section are two different components and I can not figure out how to make a click in Items section change the state of the list section.

Items Section:

```
import Item from "./Item";

function ItemSection() {
  const Items = [{ title: "DOMAIN", cost: 109 }];
  return (
    <div>
         <Item title={Items[0].title} cost={Items[0].cost} onClick={() => this.clickHandler(title, cost)}></Item>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ItemSection;
```

List Section:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function ListItems(props) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);
  const [cost, setCost] = useState(props.cost);

  const clickHandler = (mTitle, mCost) => {
    setTitle(mTitle);
    setCost(mCost);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td> {title} </td>
          <td> ${cost} </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ListItems;
```

Item:

```
function Item(props) {

  return (
    <div>
      <button>{props.title}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Item;
```

Comment: Depending on how you are setting ListItem and Item you can either use useContext hook to pass the data if its entirely separate. If they are set-up in some common file you can make use of useState hook and pass a helper function to the button to update it based on the value and use the state value where you want to display. You can also make use of redux but wouldn't recommend unless there is a lot of data involved

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you've two components: ItemSection and ListItems and you want to call a function in ListItems, that is defined in ItemSection? Is it the correct understanding?

If yes, then you can define your function in `ItemSection` and send that function as prop in `ItemSection`

In `ItemSection`:

```
    <ListItems sampleFunction = {(e)=>sampleFunction(e)}/>
```

In `ListItems`:

```
    interface Props{
    sampleFunction: Function;
    }
```

and:

```
    <button OnClick = {props.sampleFunction}>{props.title}</button>
```

This is just a pseudo code.